# How do I get sound to play through USB headphones?

Tags: 16.04, usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

## My Problem

I've recently reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on my system.  I usually use a Bluetooth headset with a microphone.  It worked perfectly before I reinstalled, but now when I go into the sound settings and select my headphones:

[image: Analog Output]

[image: USB-Ear Microphone]

It still plays sound through the speakers as if I never selected the headphones.

## Solutions that didn't Work

- Selecting the sound card through **PulseAudio Volume Control**
- Selecting the sound card through **Alsamixer**
- Reducing the *Master* volume and increasing the *Headphone* volume in **Alsamixer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's kind of embarrassing.  Everything is working just fine now after an update and a reboot.  I apologize for wasting your time.